# adding a function to jquery countdowntimer plugin jCountdown

Tags: jquery, plugins

i would like to use this plugin, but it does not have an option to stop counting, or change the countdown timer value:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCountdown

how can this featuer be added?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the example on that very link shows how the countdown timer value is changed to show only the days, and I think that if you wrap the setup for your countdown timer in an `if` statement comparing the [current date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getDate.asp) to the target date, you could choose to not show the timer.  If the timer is something like 5 minutes away, then you should create a tick function that also checks to see if the current tick is less than the target date and hide the countdown. Effectively stopping it. I assume you could also re-setup the countdown timer to change it's target date.